# Table is not updating after post in Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am displaying a table and a form on a page but when I submit new data with the form , the table is not updating, i tried refreshing the page to see new data. I'm totally new in angular and I don't know what's the actual problem.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
  </head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css"
  integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css"
integrity="sha384-fLW2N01lMqjakBkx3l/M9EahuwpSfeNvV63J5ezn3uZzapT0u7EYsXMjQV+0En5r" crossorigin="anonymous">

<script
              src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"
              integrity="sha256-BbhdlvQf/xTY9gja0Dq3HiwQF8LaCRTXxZKRutelT44="
              crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"
integrity="sha384-0mSbJDEHialfmuBBQP6A4Qrprq5OVfW37PRR3j5ELqxss1yVqOtnepnHVP9aJ7xS" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

  <body>
    <div ng-app="myApp">
      <div class="container">
        <div ng-controller="getCtrl">
            <table class="table table-stripped">
              <tr>
                <th>Nombre</th>
                <th>Apellido</th>
              </tr>
              <tr ng-repeat = "user in users">
                 <td>{{user.name}}</td>
                 <td>{{user.lastName}}</td>
              </tr>
            </table>

            <div class="row" >

              <form name="userForm" ng-submit="formSubmit()">
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label>Nombre</label>
                  <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control" ng-model="user.name">
                  <span ng-show="errorName">{{errorName}}</span>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                  <label>Apellido</label>
                  <input type="text" name="lastName" class="form-control" ng-model="user.lastName">
                  <span ng-show="errorName">{{errorName}}</span>
                </div>
                <div style="text-align:center">
                  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" >Insertar</button>
                </div>
              </form>
            </div>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>

    <script src="node_modules/angular/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

and the js file

```
var app = angular.module('myApp',[]);

app.controller('getCtrl',['$scope','$http',function($scope,$http){
  $http.get("http://127.0.0.1:3000/api/Users")
  .then(function(response){
    $scope.users = response.data;
  });

  $scope.errorName =false;

  $scope.formSubmit = function(){
    $http.post("http://127.0.0.1:3000/api/Users",$scope.user)
    .then(function(response){

    });
  };
}]);
```

**My solution**

This is my solution I'm totally noob on angular ,I don't know  nothing about good practices ,It is a good solution?

```
var app = angular.module('myApp',[]);

app.controller('getCtrl',['$scope','$http',function($scope,$http){

  $scope.makeGetRequest = function(){
    $scope.users = {};

    $http.get("http://127.0.0.1:3000/api/Users")
    .then(function(response){
      $scope.users = response.data;
    });
  }
  $scope.errorName =false;
  $scope.makeGetRequest();

  $scope.formSubmit = function(){
    $http.post("http://127.0.0.1:3000/api/Users",$scope.user)
    .then(function(response){
      $scope.makeGetRequest();
    });
  };
}]);
```

Comment: how do you know there are changes? do you need to do a get? does the post include the changes? you aren't adding anything to scope on the success.

Comment: Have you tried my answer @AFS ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to locally display it or get the list again on the success callback.

Simply try this.

```
$scope.formSubmit = function(){
    $http.post("http://127.0.0.1:3000/api/Users",$scope.user)
    .then(function(response){
       //to update the local array with the posted object
       $scope.users.push($scope.user);
    });
  };
```

Hope it helps